# Renormalization of Two Scalar Field Theory at Tree-Level and One-Loop Levels

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory, dimensional-regularization

I have been given a problem on renormalization, but due to my inexperience, I don't understand what to do with it. Here is the statement:

Consider a theory of two real scalar fields $\phi$ and $\Phi$ in $(3+1)$ dimensions with the interaction Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}\kappa \phi^2 \Phi^2 - \frac{1}{4!}\lambda_1 \phi^4 - \frac{1}{4!}\lambda_2 \Phi^4,
$$
where the coupling constants $\kappa, \lambda, g > 0$. Suppose the masses of the fields $\phi$ at energies $E \ll M$ are described by a theory with an effective interaction Lagrangian:
$$
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4!}g\phi^4+\cdots,
$$
where $\cdots$ denotes operators of higher dimensions. Demand the correspondence between the two theories, i.e., both lead to the same result, for example, for the scattering amplitude $\phi\phi\rightarrow\phi\phi$ at the threshold at the renormalization scale $\mu = M$. Find the relation between the renormalized constants $g$ and $\kappa, \lambda_{1,2}$ at $\mu = M$ at the tree (LO) and one-loop (NLO) levels.

Could you provide step-by-step guidance on how to solve it? May be there any sources where it has already been solved?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include what you have tried ? In particular, can you compute the renormalized $\phi\phi\to \phi\phi$ scattering amplitude at LO and NLO, in both theories ?